# Folium Map deletes all JavaScript in document

Tags: javascript, python, html

Every time I create a folium map with python it saves however erases all JavaScript code I have coded to the map.html document. How can I stop this? I want my own JavaScript into the folium map.

Cheers :)

Comment: I have no idea what is your problem. Maybe you shouldn't put code directly to `map.html` but you should use Python to put this code in file when you generate map. OR put JavaScript in separated file `.js` and include it to `map.html`

Comment: Sorry, first question ever asked.

Comment: @Angus42 Just wanted you to know that your question led me to furas` answer and it was quite helpful! It might be worth coming back and adding a little more detail to your question so that other people will be led here by a search more quickly. Stack can feel harsh at times but it's full of good answers. +1 for helping me find my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation shows [Using folium with flask](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/flask.html) and there you can see function `._repr_html_()`

This function gives `HTML` which you can put in own `HTML` and save all in file.

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
folium_html = m._repr_html_()

html = f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>STACKOVERFLOW EXAMPLE</h1>

{folium_html}

<script>alert('My JavaScript Code');</script>

</body>
</html>
"""

with open('map.html', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(html)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I found that `m._repr_html_()` is used to generate `iframe` for `Jupyter` but original `save()` uses `m.get_root().render()` to get full `HTML`. But there are other functions to get separatelly parts for `head`, `body`, `script` (which `render()` uses to generate full `HTML`) and it can be used to generate own `HTML`.

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
   
root = m.get_root()

#print(root.render())  # used by `save()`

folium_head   = root.header.render()
folium_body   = root.html.render()
folium_script = root.script.render()

html = f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

{folium_head}

</head>

<body>

<h1>STACKOVERFLOW EXAMPLE</h1>

{folium_body}

<script>

{folium_script}

alert('My JavaScript Code');
</script>

</body>

</html>
"""

with open('map.html', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(html)
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems you can add elemenets also to code generated by `save()`

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
   
root = m.get_root()

# add to `<head>` before folium elements
#root.header.add_child(folium.Element("<style> ... </style>"))

# add to `<body>` before folium elements
root.html.add_child(folium.Element("<h1>STACKOVERFLOW EXAMPLE</h1>"))

# add to `<script>` before folium elements
#root.script.add_child(folium.Element("alert('My JavaScript Code');"))

# add folium elements
#root.render()  # used by `save()`
m.render()      # used by `save()`

# add to `<head>` after folium elements
#root.header.add_child(folium.Element("<style> ... </style>"))

# add to `<body>` after folium elements
#root.html.add_child(folium.Element("<h1>STACKOVERFLOW EXAMPLE</h1>"))

# add to `<script>` after folium elements
root.script.add_child(folium.Element("alert('My JavaScript Code');"))
  
m.save('test.html')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry if questions was hard to explain :)

Comment: I added another example.